# iPhone:don't want to exit game while ring/silent switch turns on from turns off mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, avaudioplayer

I am working on app in which audio file playing very vital role.

for playing audio file I am using **AVaudioPlayer** in my app.

but one problem is suppose device is in silent mode and user starts running the app

and suppose he/she turns on silent/ring switch in the middle of the app.

right now he/she must exit the game but I want such kind of functionality in

which He/she should not exit the app and in the middle of the app user should be

able to hear the sound when he turns on the ring/silent switch from the device.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I think I may have provided some false information (and you said that the question I linked to was not relevant to your situation.)  My apologies for misunderstanding.  Perhaps this documentation will be of some use to you.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html Specifically, if you configure your audio session correctly, audio should play continuously without the user ever having to exit the app.

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps have the ability to play music in the background whether they be games or not, since multitasking was introduced in iOS.

See the following tutorial.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/

Whether its legit for a game to do this I seriously question.  But thats your call.